# Is this the reasoning behind $\bot\vdash B$ (rule of explosion)?

Tags: logic

Assuming that a $\bot$ indicates we have two contradictory statements $A$ and $\neg A$, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) this can be the reasoning behind $\bot\vdash B$:

1. since $A$ is true, "$A$ or $B$" is also true
2. "$A$ or $B$" and $\neg A$ being true, means $B$ is true

Now is my assumption correct and hence this the logic behind $\bot\vdash B$? If not how does this rule make sense?

Comment: Can you specify your system used? This isn't the first time I've asked you.

Comment: Refer to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436136/328173): in step 2 you used the first or-elim, which requires "rule of explosion" if you only assume the second or-elim, which would make your proof circular. However, you can't get the second or-elim from the first or-elim, so you will have a hard time if you only accept the first as or-elim.

Comment: Correct; in Natural Deduction you can *derive* $\bot$E with *modus tollendo ponens*, and vice versa. Thus, thebtwo hace the same "deductive strength".

Comment: The rule makes perfectly sense in classical and intuitionistic logic, where contradictions are "forbidden". Consider the standard def of *logical consequence*: $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ **iff** there is no valuation making all of $\Gamma$ true and $\varphi$ false and apply it to $\Gamma = \{ A \lnot A \}$; for every $B$ it is true that there is no valuation making all of $A$ and $\lnot A$ true and $B$ false, irrespective of the truth value of $B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you please tell how we can derive MTP from $\bot$ Elim?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Also I think we can't exactly derive $\bot\vdash B$ from MTP in natural deduction but can derive $A,\neg A\vdash B$.

Comment: 1) $\bot$ --- premise; 2) $B \lor \bot$ --- from 1) by $\lor$-intro; 3) $\bot$ --- 1) repeated; 4) $\bot \to \bot$, i.e. $\lnot \bot$ --- from 3) by $\to$-intro; 5) $B$ from 2) and 4) by *modus tollendo ponens*.

Comment: For the other derivation: 1) $A \lor B$ --- premise; 2) $\lnot B$ --- premise; 3) $B$ --- assumed from 1) for $\lor$-elim; 4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\to$-elim; 5) $A$ --- from 3) by $\bot$-elim; 6) $A$ --- assumed from 1) by $\lor$-elim. Having derived $A$ from assumptions $A$ (in 6) and $B$ (in 3-5) we can derive $A$ from 1) by $\lor$-elim.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA For driving $\bot\vdash B$ I can't understand why you've repeated 1 in step 3 and how you've made the conclusion of step 4   :(   (and what is i.e here ?!)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Also please check my other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447474/is-how-i-derive-bot-vdash-varphirule-of-esxplosion-from-modus-tollendo-pon I've asked about deriving rule of explosion from MTP ^^

Comment: @KennyLau I know no more than the fact I'm using classical logic :D

Comment: Look at the truth table for $A\implies B$. If $A$ is false, then it doesn't matter whether $B$ is true or false, $A\implies B$ will be true. In other words, all things follow from a falsehood. Likewise, if $B$ is true, then it doesn't matter whether $A$ is true or false, $A\implies B$ will be true. In other words, a truism follows from all things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in various posts, there are slightly different presentations of the calculus of *Natural Deduction*: [here](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) is a "good" one.

For a more detailded treatment, you can see the beautiful book:

- Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=8RUOAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2013).

The differences are mainly limited to the "management" of the *negation* sign (see e.g. this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658262/what-is-the-correct-reading-of-bot) ).

The above set of rules can be "streamlined" further, avoiding $\lnot$ and introducing it as an abbreviation for $P \to \bot$.

With this decision, we can remove the two rules: $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I because they are simple consequences of $\to$E and $\to$I and the abrreviation.

$\bot$E (*ex falso*) is needed for [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/). If we remove $\bot$ and the $\bot$E rule, we get the so-called [Minimal Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic).

As discussed elsewhere, *ex falso* and *modus tollendo ponens* are inter-derivable; but the use of the last one as primitive is contrary to the "spirit" of ND, where every connective (except for $\bot$: the lack of an $\bot$I rule is clearly motivated by the need to avoid the inconsistecy of the calculus) is "defined" by a couple of rules: the intro- and the elim- rules.

*Mtp* instead, uses both $\lnot$ and $\lor$.

*End of the "resumé"*.

---

Regarding $\to$-intro, I'm using the case: $A \vdash B \to A$.

This is perfectly sound: if $A$ is (assumed to be) *true*, then $B \to A$ is also *true*, under assumption $A$; see [von Plato, page 33](https://books.google.it/books?id=8RUOAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33).

This "intuition" can be formalized through the fact that we can clearly derive $A$ from assumption $A$. But we can always add "unnecessary" assumptions; thus, we have also $A,B \vdash A$ and so, by $\to$-intro: $A \vdash B \to A$.

But the last explanation amounts exactly to the "insertion" in the derivation of a new assumption and thus the technique, of "re-iterating" $A$ under assumption $A$ (as you have done in your [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447474/is-how-i-derive-bot-vdash-varphirule-of-esxplosion-from-modus-tollendo-pon)) is a legitimate application of it.

In the above comments, I've played with the abbreviation:

1) assumed $\bot$

2) then: $\bot \vdash \bot$ --- by reiteration

3) $\vdash \bot \to \bot$ --- by $\to$I, discharging 1)

4) $\vdash \lnot \bot$ --- by abbreviation

and more: 5) $\vdash \top$ --- the TRUE: a new abbreviation.

We have proved $\vdash \top$, and this is consistent with the "completeness" of the calculus: we want to prove all formulas that are always true, and the TRUE constant is one of them.

---

---

In [Hilbert-style proof systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_systems#Implication_and_negation) we can use $\to$ and $\lnot$, like Frege, or $\lor$ and $\lnot$, like Russell-Whitehead. Or, see Tarski-Bernays and Church, we can have $\bot$ as primitive.

Again, some variations: Tarski uses the axiom: $\bot \to A$, while Church uses Double Negation: $((A \to \bot) \to \bot) \to A$.

And more... we can "fill the gap" with ND using a couple of axioms for every conncetives.

Comment: Hmmm I think regarding deriving $\bot\vdash B$ from MTP in your comment above, we can easily remove step 3 so we'll have:
1)$\;\bot$ --- premise; 2)$\;B\vee\bot$ --- $\vee$ Intro 1; 3)$\;\bot\rightarrow\bot$, i.e. $\neg \bot$ --- $\rightarrow$ Intro 1; 4)$\;B$ --- MTP 2,3