# Example of $F\to T?$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

For $F\to T$ we are starting from a false point and concluded the result to be false and the result of $F\to F$ is true. But how someone can start at a false point and prove something correct? I am talking about $F\to T$. I know that result of $F\to T$ is true because it's not breaking the `if..then` promise. I am searching a practical example where someone has started with a false proposition and proved something correct?

Comment: But, having said that, we have the so-called [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion): "according to which any statement can be proven from a contradiction. That is, once a contradiction has been asserted, any proposition (including their negations) can be inferred from it". Thus, from a contradiction we can correctly infer true as well as false conclusions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but the thing you wrote is a subset of meaning of P -> Q. This is the thing we often do in proof by induction where we prove P(n+1) by P(n) and write P(n) -> P(n+1).

Comment: See this recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447140/is-this-the-reasoning-behind-bot-vdash-b-rule-of-explosion) for a discussion of the inference rule.

Comment: Ok; thus, the "meaning" of the rule is: from a contradiction, anything follows (*ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet*).

Comment: Proof: 1) $0=1$ --- assumed; 2) from arithmetical axioms, we can prove that $0 \ne 1$; thus: 3) **contradiction !** and applying the above rule: 4) $1=1$. In this way, we have proved that from $0=1$ we can prove $1=1$ and thus, as per your comment, we conclude with: $0=1 \to 1=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

If $3 = -3$, then $9=9$ (obtained by squaring both sides--if you square both sides of an equation, the result will be an equation).

Comment: this is a good example of "anything follows from a contradiction"

Answer (score 1):

The fact the logically $P\implies Q$ is true when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true does not mean that one ever attempts to prove $Q$ from a premise $P$ known to be false. Once the implication is proved true it is always used by invoking modes ponens, that is once $P\implies Q$ is established, and $P$ is established, one deduces $Q$. So, there is no practical scenario where you would establish that $Q$ is true by first establishing that $P\implies Q$ is true and then show that $Q$ is false. Simply because there is no valid inference rule that permits that.

Comment: “So, there is no practical scenario where you would establish that Q is true by first establishing that P⟹Q is true and then show that Q is false.” There is no theoretical scenario either. “P⟹Q is true when P is false and Q is true” allows to establish P⟹Q, and you are trying to establish Q.

Comment: Yes @beroal that's what I said.